# Trying to detect a call to my web app made by facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, httprequest

In my asp.net MVC app, I'm trying to know if this is facebook who is calling one of my urls (when a link to my site is shared as a FB status and FB tries to get some meta tags for opengraph). I have tried URlReferrer, which is empty, and UserHostName which shows an IP addr.

Comment: Can you attempt a DNS lookup of the IP Address?

Answer (score 0):

You could do as Tejs suggests, something like:

```
IPHostEntry IpEntry = Dns.GetHostByAddress(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress); 
//OR
IPHostEntry IpEntry = Dns.GetHostByAddress(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
if(IpEntry.HostName.Contains("facebook.com"))
{
  //Coming from facebook.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this can be done like so:

```
if ((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Request.UserAgent) && HttpContext.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("facebookexternalhit")) ||
    ((HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer != null) && HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToLower().Contains("facebook.com")))
```

This way I know if Facebook is grabbing opengraph data or if someone clicks the shared link from a facebook page.